# Why are dots in track name confusing searches via Spotify Web API?

Tags: javascript, python, api, get, spotify

For example, we want to search for a track `Sixx:A.M. Life Is Beautiful`. To do it, go to [Spotify Console](https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-search-item/?q=Sixx%3AA.M.%20Life%20Is%20Beautiful&type=track&market=&limit=1&offset=). The `total` int the response is zero. Nothing found.

Now, go to the site. Paste the same text `Sixx:A.M. Life Is Beautiful` into the search field. The result is more than one.

What's the problem?

[Description](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/search/search/) search request

**Response**:

```
{
  "tracks": {
    "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=Sixx%3AA.M.+Life+Is+Beautiful&type=track&offset=0&limit=1",
    "items": [],
    "limit": 1,
    "next": null,
    "offset": 0,
    "previous": null,
    "total": 0
  }
}
```

**Site url**:

```
https://open.spotify.com/search/Sixx%3AA.M.%20Life%20Is%20Beautiful
```

**UPDATE**

If dots are removed from the string - Sixx:`AM` Life Is Beautiful - Spotify Console returns the needed track! But for example `P.O.D. Find My Way` - dots do not interfere, the result is given with them. I don't understand how it works...

Comment: Can you post the response for Sixx:AM Life Is Beautiful? I guess there must be a mismatch in the actual name and the name they're using to match the search result frim console.

Comment: @SibasishMohanty the response is already in the post

Comment: Did you try to Base64 the URl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `query` parameter is not a simple "search string", like the website. Is a string that has fields and operators, as you can read in [the documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/search/search/#writing-a-query---guidelines). Passing the user input directly as a `query` parameter can lead to problems, as the user can write a filter o an operator without knowing it. You should either:

- Notify the user about this. The user will write operators and such knowing what he is doing.
- Parse the string received and create a proper `query` parameter.

I guess that Spotify don't like weird characters in their query, as dots and such (the same as Google for example, but Google filter them), so I recommend to just parse the string, remove dots, convert all non alphanumeric characters to spaces and make all the string lower case so there are no operators (as documentation says that operators are upper case). So:

```js
function cleanQuery(str) {
  return encodeURIComponent(str.replace(/\./g, "").replace(/[^0-9a-z]/gi, " ").toLowerCase());
}

console.log("Clean \"Sixx:A.M. Life Is Beautiful\":", cleanQuery("Sixx:A.M. Life Is Beautiful"));
```

I've made a query with the returned result and it worked:[image]

Note that this is a fast test. I noticed that the problem with dots is that they are not the *first word*. Maybe there are more characters with problems, as dashes, for example. This is going to be a trial-and-error thingy, as the documentation is kinda vague (not documenting dots, for example).